# two floating divs to keep same height and have vertically aligned content

Tags: html, css

I have two floating divs side by side. The one on the right has a height that can vary, depending on the content.

I am trying to get the left div to grow with the right div, and also have the the contents of the left div be vertically centered.

[Here is my jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/callcan/bnvtf1k5/2/)

CSS:

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.floatFirst {
  float: left;    
  border : 1px solid red;
}
.floatSecond {
  float: left;    
  border : 1px solid blue;
}
.divToBeVerticallyCentered {
  border: 1px solid green;
  position: relative; 
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

HTML:

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="floatFirst">
     <p class="divToBeVerticallyCentered">this should be vertically centered</p>
  </div>
  <div class="floatSecond">
     <p>this is some text</p>
     <p>this is some text</p>
     <p>this is some text</p>
     <p>this is some text</p>
     <p>this is some text</p>
     <p>this is some text</p>
     <p>this is some text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You're asking two separate questions here. I suggest you search "equal height columns" and "vertical centering" here and with Google. Also, consider not using floats. Inline-block display may simplify things.

Comment: It's really just one question. I have searched for both separately. But I need to have them work together,,,hence the one question. I may be able to get rid of the floats.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you adjust your CSS from using floats to table cells you can get what you want with this:

```css
.container {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.floatFirst {
    display:table-cell;
    border : 1px solid red;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
.floatSecond {
    display:table-cell;
    border : 1px solid blue;
}
.divToBeVerticallyCentered {
    border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="floatFirst">
        <!-- this needs to grow with floatSecond-->
        <p class="divToBeVerticallyCentered">this should be vertically centered</p>
    </div>
    <div class="floatSecond">
        <p>this is some text</p>
        <p>this is some text</p>
        <p>this is some text</p>
        <p>this is some text</p>
        <p>this is some text</p>
        <p>this is some text</p>
        <p>this is some text</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think using table instead of divs or table-cell on both divs would be the best option, both columns would grow simultaneously.

As to the vertical alignment, your code will work (relative with top: 50%) if you get rid of the translateY, or you could just simply use vertical-align for that